# Date input calendar icon not showing in mobile

Tags: html, date, field

I have select date input field, there is icon of calendar when I check in desktop its looks fine but when I check in mobile the icon change into down icon, mobile design attached below, please check. Thanks in advance!

[image]

```html
<div class="form-group row">
                          <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="date-month-year"/>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: The appearance of the `<input type="date">` varies between browsers. If you want it to look the same, you can either [try to style the native input](https://dev.to/codeclown/styling-a-native-date-input-into-a-custom-no-library-datepicker-2in), or use a custom Javascript plugin.